# gulp notify - getting rid of annoying ballon popup (on windows)

Tags: gulp, gulp-notify

I'm using gulp-notify within the gulp pipeline like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  notify = require('gulp-notify');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp
     .pipe(notify({ message: "Hello, world"}));
});
```

This logs to console, but it also creates annoying balloon popup. Any way how to get rid of that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to log and not have the balloon popup, you should not use [gulp-notify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify).

I recoment using [gulp-util](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp-util) for logging. Your task will look like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
  gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp
    .on('end', function(){ gutil.log('Hello, world'); });
});
```